# SQLite3 and python not inserting rows

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

I'm trying to insert a row into my table. I've been following the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html I get the error: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: asd. asd is the value i entered for scholarship name. Heres my code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('pathfinder.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" % (table, request.form['scholarship_name'],request.form['scholarship_gpa'],request.form['scholarship_amount'], "Male",request.form['specific_essay'], "[]","[]"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider parameterization which is advised in the very link you are following:

```
# Never do this -- insecure!
symbol = 'RHAT'
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)
```

String interpolated SQL statements especially with user input from flask requests can potentially be dangerous to your database. Therefore, consider using the second argument of `execute` that binds values to placeholders, `?`, in prepared statement.

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT
sql = "INSERT INTO {} VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)".format(table)

# QUERY EXECUTION
c.execute(sql, (request.form['scholarship_name'],
                request.form['scholarship_gpa'], 
                request.form['scholarship_amount'],  
                "Male", 
                request.form['specific_essay'], 
                "[]",
                "[]")
          )
```